# How do I get my columns to balance evenly?

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

The columns don't seem to balance (lines per column not `</p>` per column) out correctly.

Have tried column-fill: balance with no joy.

As you can see from the image. There is 1 paragraph on the right with 3 on the left.

[image]

```css
.col {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 12px 0 18px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
    <p>Our vision is simple. To capture your story in the most beautifully stunning way with our imaginative and contemporary style...</p>
    <p>After photographing hundreds of weddings, we have concluded that there are 2 main types of photographers, the SNAP photographer and the STANDARD photographer.</p>
    <p>The standard photographers primary role is to capture the finest of details and moments telling the unique story of your wedding day. The snap photographer, however, is responsible for the 'hang on the wall' family and friends formal group photos.</p>
    <p>We offer Hong Kong Wedding Day Photography packages that cover both standard and snap photographers. This way you can relax and enjoy your wedding, knowing that we will capture every single moment of your special day.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is based on the answer by ercan peker.

```css
    .col {
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-count:    2;
        column-count:         2;
        -webkit-column-gap:   9px;
        -moz-column-gap:      9px;
        column-gap:           9px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col">
    Our vision is simple. To capture your story in the most beautifully stunning way with our imaginative and contemporary style...
 <br><br>
    After photographing hundreds of weddings, we have concluded that there are 2 main types of photographers, the SNAP photographer and the STANDARD photographer.
 <br><br>
    The standard photographers primary role is to capture the finest of details and moments telling the unique story of your wedding day. The snap photographer, however, is responsible for the 'hang on the wall' family and friends formal group photos.
 <br><br>
    We offer Hong Kong Wedding Day Photography packages that cover both standard and snap photographers. This way you can relax and enjoy your wedding, knowing that we will capture every single moment of your special day.
</div>
```

I have edited the answer above and came up with this. It evenly distributes the lines on each column.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It would prefer to keep the <p> for general good practice reasons. This would be specific for that number of lines as well correct?